# how to create rule (HTTP request redirections should not be open to forging attacks - RSPEC-5146) java plugin

Tags: java, security, plugins, sonarqube, rules

The rule is only available in commercial and I would like to create a custom rule about HTTP request directions

Code below is the compliant and non-compliant

```
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
            String location = req.getParameter("url");
            resp.sendRedirect(location); // Noncompliant {{non- compliant}}
        }

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
            String location = req.getParameter("url");

            if (!urlWhiteList.contains(location))
                throw new IOException();

            resp.sendRedirect(location);
        }
```

Comment: You question in not very clear. You can start reading [the documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/extend/adding-coding-rules/) and update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These rules use some more advanced algorithms for static analysis. This article https://wiki.mozilla.org/Abstract_Interpretation provides a good high-level introduction. Then you might be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_analysis

Once you grasp the basics, you can start the implementation by following https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/docs/CUSTOM_RULES_101.md